# Collapse run-on whitespace

Tags: python, regex, whitespace

How would I collapse run-on whitespace in python?

```
"a b   c   d      e" --> "a b c d e"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming

```
s = 'a b   c   d      e'
```

then

```
' '.join(s.split())
'a b c d e'
```

will give you the specified output.

This works by using [split()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) to break the string into into a list of individual characters `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` and then joining them again with a single space in-between using the [join()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) function into a string. The `split()` also takes care of any leading or trailing blanks.

Based on *Simple is better than complex* (Zen of Python) in order to avoid the regex "[two problem](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)" problem :)

Comment: @downvoter A downvote ***without*** any explanation doesn't help *anyone* (OP, SO or me). This is a functional solution to OP's problem. I am happy to correct any errors or improve the answer, but that requires some constructive feedback.

Comment: @Ωmega I don't understand .. are you talking about possible invisible whitespace characters? I think OP would have mentioned that. And what if you had a sequence of tabs and blanks mixed between say "d" and "e", which would *you* retain when you "collapsed" it? The tab? The blank?

Answer (score 5):

With regex (because of the tag):

```
re.sub('\s+', ' ', "a b   c   d      e")
```

Comment: @Ωmega I can't see why you think that. Also, why downvote an answer that provides the right output?

Comment: @Ωmega If you think that's the right interpretation of the question, explain it yourself in your answer instead of wasting other people time... You are probably over thinking a simple problem (but that's not my problem)

Comment: I would suggest you use `\s{2,}` instead. This will leave single spaces alone instead of replacing them with themselves. Still, +1.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about leading spaces for first element and trailing spaces for the last one, use:

```
re.sub('\s+(?=\s)', '', str)
```

If you do, then solution that removes also those leading and trailing spaces is:

```
re.sub('(?:^\s+|\s+(?=\s)|\s+$)', '', str)
```

Comment: `^` and `$` are already zero-width assertions; there's no need to wrap them in lookarounds.

Comment: I think @Levon's answer is the best one there could be for this problem, so why should I write another one? What makes you think that (assuming we're dealing with mixed whitespaces) the last one is the one you should keep? Why not the first one? Why make assumptions like this at all?

Comment: @TimPietzcker - There are rules (most coders never heard of it) regarding specification for IT, default rules, common misunderstandings, etc. At university I attempted we had a course about that. Applying those rules to OP's question >> (1) Coder should not assuming that white-space is a space-bar only. (2) Default string truncation is from right...